# Нужна помощь в ассемблере поправить код

Tags: ассемблер

Нужно отредактировать код, чтобы он стал более упрощенным

Comment: Ну у вас и так идеальный код, как можно упростить код, состоящий из 0 строк?)

Answer (score 2):

Все сделано, результат в ответе:

```
; самый простой код во вселенной
```

Comment: Отличный код - простой, понятный и задокументированный )

Comment: Может оставите свою посту скину вам, сюда не получается добавить

Comment: Нет. Если ты решил стать программистом то задание разместить правильно свой вопрос на стеке это твоя первая практическая задача. Этот вопрос закрыт, создавай новый правильно и надлежащим образом его оформив.